# Сложный UPDATE (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Одним UPDATE надо решить следующую проблему:
Если `m_bid != 0` - записать это значение в `smax`.
Иначе, записать в `smax` наименьшее из двух значений: `m_bid` из `shops_table`, либо `max * bid_part`. Я пробовал справиться с этим на тестовых таблицах и по частям. Такой UPDATE:

```
UPDATE cat_table t0
JOIN (
    SELECT sid, m_bid, max, bid_part
    FROM cat_table
) t1
SET t0.smax=
CASE
    WHEN t1.m_bid!=0 THEN t1.m_bid
    ELSE
    CASE
        WHEN 1<t1.max*t1.bid_part THEN 1
        ELSE t1.max*t1.bid_part
    END
END;
```

Отрабатывает корректно. Начинаю усложнять:

```
UPDATE cat_table t0
JOIN (
    SELECT sid, m_bid, max, bid_part
    FROM cat_table
) t1
JOIN (
    SELECT m_bid
    FROM shops_table sh
    WHERE t1.sid=sh.sid
) t2
SET t0.smax=
CASE
    WHEN t1.m_bid!=0 THEN t1.m_bid
    ELSE
    CASE
        WHEN t2.m_bid<t1.max*t1.bid_part THEN t2.m_bid
        ELSE t1.max*t1.bid_part
    END
END;
```

Ошибка

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't1.sid' in 'where clause'
```

Что мешает ему "зацепить" sid из первого SELECT? Как исправить?

Comment: а зачем вы делаете вложенные кейсы?

Comment: Напишите UPDATE только по второму варианту. А потом в него добавьте CASE.

Comment: Т.к. три варианта развития событий

Comment: А ещё - для выбора меньшего из значений есть специальная функция LEAST().

Comment: @Akina не пойму, что имеется ввиду _Напишите UPDATE только по второму варианту. А потом в него добавьте CASE._

Comment: Вот что тут непонятного. Представьте, что *записать в smax наименьшее из двух значений: m_bid из shops_table, либо max * bid_part* нужно в любом случае, и напишите.

Comment: @Akina, извините, но яснее не стало. Вариантов развития событий три, почему я буду писать UPDATE только для второго и третьего?

Comment: "Второе  и третье", с учётом упомянутой выше функции - это ОДИН вариант, а не два.

Comment: а синтаксис `case when... when .. else ..` не поддерживается что ли в mysql ?

Comment: @Akina один, отлично, но первый почему не надо учитывать?

Comment: а вам говорят про `case when ... then t1.m_bid else least(t2.m_bid,. t1.max * t1.bid_part) end`

Comment: @teran благодарю. Я учту это, будет компактнее, но как решить проблему с SELECT. Вопрос ведь изначально в нем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```
UPDATE
  cat_table t0
  JOIN shops_table sh ON (
    t0.sid=sh.sid
  )
SET t0.smax =
  IF(
    t0.m_bid != 0,
    t0.m_bid,
    LEAST(sh.m_bid, t0.max*t0.bid_part)
  )
```

Comment: t1 откуда взяться?

Comment: В строке ` t1.sid=sh.sid` - ошибка. Должно быть ` t0.sid=sh.sid`. @AntonShchyrov, благодарю на тестовой сработало